# Unable to close apps from mission control, Mavericks OS X

Tags: macos, mission-control

Unable to close apps from mission control, Mavericks OS X.

I do not get an "X" to close, and after downloading BetterTouchTool and attempting the close window with cursor over window (which says is suppose to work in mission control) I still have no luck. After reading some reviews I am going to wait downloading Yosemite and become comfortable with Mavericks. New Mac user as of 2/16/15.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, you don't close apps from Mission Control.

You use it to bring an app to the front, change Spaces, add or remove Spaces - it doesn't act directly on the apps themselves.

See [Mac Basics: Use Mission Control to switch between apps or spaces](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204100)